# DirectoryNotFoundException when trying to read Picture Library using Linq

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, list, linq, picture-library

I am trying to read a picture library named "ImageLibrary" as follows:

```
SPList list = web.GetList("ImageLibrary");
```

But I am getting following error:

> DirectoryNotFoundException

How do I read ImageLibrary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPWeb.GetList("") gets a-a list by its server relative path. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlist.aspx) API description.

So to get your list try to pass something like "/Lists/ImageLibrary". Or appropriate server relative path.

Hope it helps,

Andrew